# Ubuntu Server high processor and memory usage

Tags: server, lamp

A friend of mine is having issues with his Ubuntu server. He is wondering about the high processor usage. I don't know about the memory though. Plus, he's using Plesk. When I checked his Control Panel, I don't see any installations of Wordpress or any other applications. So, the entire LAMP stack might have been installed manually via SSH. I will be attaching some of the screenshots.

I have no idea how to optimize it.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

Another thing, I am planning to implement Cloudflare. But, I don't know if I have to manually change all of the settings of the domains or I will just install the Cloudflare application in Plesk.

Answer (score 0):

Change in php.ini to:

`max_execution_time = 300`

`max_input_time = 600`

`memory_limit = 256M`

restart apache